Enable or Disable the coponents According to increment or decrement the values
In my React e-commerce project app, I use increment or decrement functionality by clicking the add or remove icon. I explain, how this app works. Display all items or products on the screen by applying the map method on an array of objects. during the map method applying CardComponent rendered and all products shown on the screen according to CardCOmponet formatting. CardComponent has 2 components one is NumberInput.js and the second is AddToCartBtn.js. CardComponent Shows like
CardComponet.js
<Card>
      <LikeButton/>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia ... />
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography> .... </Typography>
        <Typography> .... </Typography>
        <Typography> ... </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <Stack>
        <NumberInput ... />
        <AddToCartBtn ... />
      </Stack>
    </Card>

I want firstly, only shows CardActionArea, cardConent and AddToCartBtn. When the User clicks AddToCartBtn this time NumberInput is enabled and AddToCartBtn is disabled and also the value of the input field is 1. When the user decrements the value from 1 to 0 by using the remove icon automatically enable the AddToCartBtn.
In this app, I use useStates and ReduxToolkit. the increment or decrement functionality is handled with reduxToolkit and AddToCartBtn functionality is handled with useStates and props.
In this task, I have 2 tasks first, enable the numberInput and disable AddToCartBtn and second enable AddToCartBtn when the value of inputField is 0 and disable NumberInput. I have done the first task but the second task has issues or didn't work.
App.js
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

const handleAddToCart = (item) => {
  const newArray = cartItems.find((element) => element?.id === item?.id);
  if (newArray) return;
    // console.log("Action worked", newArray);
    setCartItems((pre) => [...pre, item]);
};

const handleDeleteToCart = (item) => {
    if (cart[item.id] > 0) {
      setCart((pre) => ({ ...pre, [item.id]: (pre[item.id] || 0) - 1 }));
    }
    **else if(cart[item.id] === 0){
      setCart()
    }**

    const updateItems = cartItems.filter((data) => data?.id !== item?.id);
    setCartItems(updateItems);
    
  };

In redux, counterSlice.js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  count: {},
};
const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state, action) => {
      const id = action?.payload;   
      state.count = { ...state.count, [id]: (state.count?.[id] || 0) + 1 };
    },
    decrement: (state, action) => {
      let minimumLimit = 0;
      const id = action.payload;
      if (!state.count?.[id] || state.count?.[id] === minimumLimit) return;
      state.count = { ...state.count, [id]: (state.count?.[id] || 0) - 1 };
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;


NumberInput.js
function NumberInput({ id, cart }) {
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.count);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

return (
    <>
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="space-around"
        alignItems="center"
        spacing={0}
        border={1}
        sx={{ border: "1px solid red" }}
      >
        {cart?.[id] ? (
          <>
            <Button onClick={() => dispatch(decrement(id))}>
              <RemoveIcon/>
            </Button>

            <input
              type="text"
              value={count?.[id] || 0}
            />
            <Button onClick={() => dispatch(increment(id))}>
              <AddIcon ... />
            </Button>
          </>
        ) : null}
      </Stack>
</>
  );
}
export default NumberInput;



if you are trying to conditionally disable/enable a component, react makes it very simple.  just pass a boolean into the element's "disabled" prop.  for example: Click me
